# How to apply pagemod destroy() method?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an SDK extension that injects script on pages. In the addon options there is 1 bool that used to turn that script on or off.

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs;
function onPrefChange(prefName) {
    if (prefs.showMAC) {  
        //if true - apply pagemod             
        pageMod.PageMod({
            include: "*.mydomen.net",
            attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
            contentScriptFile: data.url("proxy_open.js")
        });
    }else{
        //if false - remove pagemod
    }
}

require("sdk/simple-prefs").on("showMAC", onPrefChange);
```

I'm new to all that extensions stuff and can't find any information about how to apply `destroy()` correctly, can anyone explain how to do this correctly? I've tried `pageMod.destroy();` that gives "not a function" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `var mod = null` and then `mod = pageMod` works like a charm.

```
var mod = null;
var prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs;
function onPrefChange(prefName) {
    if (prefs.showMAC) {
        mod = pageMod.PageMod({
            include: "*.mydomen.net",
            attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
            contentScriptFile: data.url("proxy_open.js")
        });
    }else{
        mod.destroy();
    }
}

require("sdk/simple-prefs").on("showMAC", onPrefChange)
```

Comment: I tried this and I keep getting `mod is undefined`.  I think it is because if the pref is false, then it tries to destroy it before it was defined.  I guess you can't destroy null with destroy.